# Не работает перенос строки

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Храню в JSON характеристики товаров. При выводе пытаюсь заменить все запятые на перенос строки.

```
  {{ $char= json_decode($prod[0]->characteristic)}}
   {{ str_replace(',',PHP_EOL,$char) }}
    {{ nl2br($char) }}
```

Выводит в таком виде:

```
Процессор: Xenos.<br /> ОЗУ: 1 ГБ,<br /> ОС: Андроид,<br /> Камера: 12 МП/5 МП,<br /> Дисплей: 5.5
```

Подскажите решение.

Comment: Вместо `{{ }}` - используйте `{!! !!}`, но подумайте о безопасности использования этого.

Comment: А есть безопасные варианты?)

Comment: откуда берется json?

Comment: Заполняется поле  в виде Характеристика: значение, потом кодируется в json и хранится в бд. Ну а дальше описал выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я всегда подозревал, что Blade  - это зло, и теперь я в этом убедился.
Возможность писать в шаблоне любой РНР код - это отличная возможность выстрелить себе в ногу. И вот в итоге здесь мы видим, как бизнес-логика во всю цветет и пахнет в шаблоне.

Чтобы сделать правильно, надо всю бизнес-логику вымести из шаблона.

И плюс надо сделать нормальное хранение параметров, без этих чудовищных запятых. Но поскольку это будет очень сложно для автора и не имеет прямого отношения к вопросу, то хотя бы вместо str_replace() надо использовать explode() для получения массива. И уже этот массив нормально выводить циклом в шаблоне.

В итоге, json_decode и explode() в обязательном порядке убираются в контроллер, а в шаблоне остается аккуратный код

```
@foreach($prod[0]->characteristic as $char)
    {{ $char }}<br>
```

Comment: А какие варианты хранения характеристик товара являются правильными? Ибо это первое, что пришло в голову

Comment: Ну вот-во-первых, [канонический ответ на англоязычном СО, почему запятые это плохо](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad). А варианты хранения есть разные, от огромной таблицы в которой каждый параметр занимает свою колонку, до noSql баз данных, например Mongo. просто в момент, когда понадобится искать товар по характеристике, база с запятыми встанет в очень неудобную позу.

Comment: Понял. Буду разбираться. Спасибо)